# Null space of A and Null space of A Transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

Let $A$ be $m \times n$ matrix and after we gone through some elementary row operations we get $U$ which is Reduced row echelon form of $A$. Then can we say that $\text{Null}(A^T) = \text{Null}(U^T$)?

Comment: or should i first take A to transpose of it then find rref. As i tried on some matrices some of them gave me the same result but it seems it was lucky. I first need to take transpose.

Comment: Elementary row operations do not change the nullspace. Elementary column operations do not generally preserve the nullspace (that is, they will usually change it). Since $U^T$ is obtained from $A^T$ via elementary column operations, you simply cannot expect them to have the same nullspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\left(\begin{array}{cr}1&1\\1&1\end{array}\right)$. Its row echelon form is $U=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&0\end{array}\right)$.

The nullspace of $A^T=A$ is $\{(x,-x)^T\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

The nullspace of $U^T=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\1&0\end{array}\right)$ is the set $\{(0,y)^T\mid y\in\mathbb{R}\}$.